# Render django_tables2.Column with select tag inside (UPDATED)

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-tables2

I've written a custom editable table with columns subclassing from `django_tables2.Column`, but keep struggling with rendering a select tag in my custom column. Considering the model:

**myapp/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from myapp.utils.enums import MyModelChoices


class MyModel(models.Model):
    bound_model = models.ForeignKey(
        SomeOtherModel,
        related_name='bound_model'
    )

    used_as = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        choices=MyModelChoices.choices()
    )
```

and my enum in **myapp/utils/enums.py**:

```
class MyModelChoices:
    __metaclass__ = EnumMeta  # Logic irrelevant

    First = 'First',
    Second = 'Second',
    Third = 'Third'
```

I end up with custom column like this:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from django.forms import ChoiceField

class ChoicesColumn(tables.Column):
    def __init__(self, choices, attrs=None, **extra):
        self.choices = choices
        kwargs = {'orderable': False, 'attrs': attrs}
        kwargs.update(extra)
        super(ChoicesColumn, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def render(self, value, bound_column):
        select = ChoiceField(choices=self.choices)
        return select.widget.render(
            bound_column.name,
            self.label_to_value(value)
        )

    def label_to_value(self, label):
        for (v, l) in self.choices:
            if l == label:
                return v
```

which is later called in my table class like this:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from myapp.models import MyModel
from myapp.tables.utils import ChoicesColumn

class MyTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column()
    used_as = ChoicesColumn(
        choices=lambda record: record.used_as.choices()
    )

    def render_name(self, record):
        return record.bound_model.name

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name', 'used_as',)
```

but still there's rendered just a plain `<td></td>` with text instead of select field. What am I doing wrong in this situation? I'm using Python 2.7, Django 1.8 and django-tables2 1.16.0. Thanks in advance for your advice!

**UPDATE**

I changed my custom column class like this:

```
class ChoicesColumn(tables.Column):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, **extra):
        kwargs = {'orderable': False, 'attrs': attrs}
        kwargs.update(extra)
        super(ChoicesColumn, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def render(self, value, bound_column):
        options = [self.render_option(c) for c in value]
        html_template = '''
                        <select name={}>{}</select>
                        '''.format(bound_column.name, options)
        return mark_safe(html_template)

    def render_option(self, choice):
        return '<option value={0}>{0}</option>'.format(choice)
```

and added a `render_options` method according to [this paragraph](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo-methods) in documentation:

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column(accessor='pk')
    # With or without accessor it doesn't work neither way
    used_as = ChoicesColumn(accessor='used_as')

    def render_name(self, record):
        return record.bound_model.name

    def render_used_as(self, record):
        return record.used_as.choices()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel,
        fields = ('name', 'options',)
```

but this method isn't even executed on render, what I've spotted while debugging, though the method before it executes when I reload the page and renders data correctly. Is that because `name` column uses the library class, and `options` column uses custom class inherited from it? If so, what is my subclass missing?

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

I figured out what was the previous problem with choices, though it didn't solve the problem :( The thing was that I was passing model instance's field `used_as`, which was set to `None`, thus it would never populate the ChoiceField. So, I rolled back my custom column class to the initial variant, and in my table class instead of

```
used_as = ChoicesColumn(
    choices=lambda record: record.used_as.choices()
)
```

I imported `MyModelChoices` enum and used it instead of model instance

```
used_as = ChoicesColumn(choices=MyModelChoices.choices())
```

and now I see the options passing to constructor, though the `render` method isn't still called for some mysterious reason =/

**LAST UPDATE AS FOR NOW**
As for the current moment my custom column and table look like this:

```
class ChoicesColumn(tables.Column):
    def __init__(self, choices, attrs=None, **extra)
        self.choices = choices
        self.choices.insert(0, ('', '------'))
        kwargs = {'orderable': False, 'attrs': attrs}
        kwargs.update(extra)
        super(ChoicesColumn, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def render(self, value, bound_column):
        select = forms.ChoiceField(choices=self.choices)
        return select.widget.render(bound_column.name, value)


class MyTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column(accessor='pk')
    used_as = ChoiceColumn(UsedAs.choices(), accessor='used_as')

    def render_name(self, record):
        return record.bound_model.name

    def render_used_as(self, record):
        if record.used_as is None:
            return ''
        return record.used_as

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name', 'used_as')
```

The `ChoiceColumn` render method and the corresponding method in table class are never called on rendering stage (unlike the other columns), and I completely give up. Please, be merciful enough either to shoot me or tell me where exactly I'm an idiot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I accidentally found out, the problem was in `accessor` attribute – when changed from

```
used_as = ChoiceColumn(UsedAs.choices(), accessor='used_as')
```

to

```
used_as = ChoiceColumn(UsedAs.choices(), accessor='pk')
```

it finally rendered. I don't understand why that happened and would be very grateful if someone explained that to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way:

If you have a Enum column (say `used_as`), you can change the renderer so that it displays the `value` (instead of the `name`). Place this in the Table definition (in `class MyTable(tables.Table)` ).

```
def render_used_as(self,value):
    v = value.split(".")[1]
    members = MyModelChoices.__members__
    return (members[v].value)
```

Note that I was using a bit of a different syntax for the Enum

```
from enum import Enum
Class MyModelChoices(Enum):
   First = 'First'
   Second = 'Second'
   Third = 'Third'
```

Note: `render_used_as` is `render_%s` with %s = variable name